# why does my pyautogui code not works good

Tags: python, pyautogui

I create a simple script to find image on the desktop ,and type 'I found it ' ,and if I hide the image the script type 'I am unable to found it'.

the problem when I add another action ,which is I want the mouse move to the position of the image. the script works good ,but when I hide the image the mouse still move to the position ,and still type I found it. But normally the code should show me I am unable to found it.
the script still working on if instead to move to else.

my code is:

```
import pyautogui
import time

location = pyautogui.locateOnScreen('image.png', confidence = 0.6)

while 1:
    if location:
        print("I found it ")
        time.sleep(2)
        print(pyautogui.moveTo(location))

    else:
        print("I am unable to found it")
```

Comment: I might have misunderstood your question, but you just check if the variable `location` exists - nothing more. It will exist after your first check, even if not a `True` statement any more.

Comment: @xtlc that's not true. Doing `if variable:` doesn't check if it exists. It checks if its value is *truthy*. If it wouldn't exist, a `NameError` would be raised...

Comment: You are right, my explanation was poor in this regard. Nevertheless the state of  `location` is never altered in the `while` loop, therefore if ending up in the `if` clause once, he will always (that's at least what the code looked like before his edit).

Comment: What do you mean with *I hide the logo*? Obviously `pyautogui` can still find. Debug why. We don't have enough information to really help here...

Comment: @xtlc I agree. The loop seems a bit pointless...

Comment: @Tomerikoo  could you please correct my code

Comment: @Tomerikoo in my cod there are two conditions : IF is the first condition :so the script found the image ,and type 'I found it 'and the mouse moves to the image. else is the second condition : so if i hide the image when the script is runing , should automaticcaly type I am unable to found it. the problem is :when i hide the image , the script still moves to the position of the image and type 'I found it ' but normally the script should moves to els

Comment: But you never change `location` inside the loop... So even if you move the window, the saved `location` is the one from the start... You need to move `location = pyautogui.locateOnScreen('image.png', confidence = 0.6)` to be ***inside*** the loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you store `pyautogui.locateOnScreen('image.png', confidence = 0.6)` in the variable `location`. Then you check the condition (`if`/`else`). But then you never recheck for `pyautogui.locateOnScreen('image.png', confidence = 0.6)`. I am still not sure what you are trying to achieve here, but at least the check needs to go into the `while`:

```
while 1:
    location = pyautogui.locateOnScreen('image.png', confidence = 0.6)
    if location:
        print("I found it ")
        time.sleep(2)
        print(pyautogui.moveTo(location))
    else:
        print("I am unable to find it")
```